# База данных. Как лучше сделать?

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят, у меня возник такой вопрос. Делаю сервис.

Имеем: БД MySQL. В каждой строке хранится конфиг юзера. Строк порядка тысячи.

Мне нужно каждую строку обойти и выполнить некие операции с данными, полученными из БД.

Как лучше это сделать? Если в цикле, то как-то бредово получается, скрипт будет обрабатываться очень долго (каждая итерация по ~30 sec).

Как лучше сделать? Посоветуйте.

**Обновление**

Полминуты - это долго, я не знаю, сколько скрипт будет обрабатываться точно, всегда по-разному. Это не зависит напрямую от моего сервера, т.к. запрос идет на другой сервер. Данных в таблице может быть больше.

Answer (score 1):

А так ли необходимо выполнять "некоторые операции" для каждого пользователя? Ведь он мог забросить ваш сервис и данные с прошлого запуска данные в итоге не изменятся.

И если другой сервер что-то делает и из-за этого все 30 секунд занимает, то как ни крути, все равно придется тратить на это 30*1000 секунд. Это можно размазать по времени (т.е. сейчас 30*100 секунд, через полчаса еще одни 30*100 и т.д.), но общее время все равно будет таким.

И почему другой сервер так долго отвечает? Может, что-то не так делаете? На крайний случай можно данные посылать, не дожидаясь ответа.

Answer (score 0):

30 сек на итерацию это крайне долго? У вас что, одна запись весит несколько МБ?
Расставьте ключи в базе.
Выгружайте все необходимое разом, после чего проходите по полученным данным и формируйте sql запросы на update, и затем выполняйте их.

Comment: Полминуты - это долго, я не знаю сколько скрипт будет обрабатываться, всегда по разному. Это не зависит на прямую от моего сервера, т.к. запрос идет на другой сервер. Данных в таблице может быть больше. Что за ключи, расскажите подробней, пожалуйста.